# How to automatically deduce T in this forwarding function?

Tags: c++

Given this code

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto make_vector(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::vector<T>{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}
```

I don't want to type `make_vector<int>(1, 2, 3, 4)`. How to get rid of T?

Comment: You want to write a new function just because `std::vector<int> {1, 2, 3, 4}` is too long? Or is your actual use case something different?

Comment: You can just use the type of the first argument, after decaying it. As given this function may not necessarily do the Right Thing for 1 or 2 arguments. What do you want it to do for those numbers of arguments, i.e., what is it that this function does that ordinary vector construction doesn't?

Comment: @Brian: The purpose is to deduce the type, which (in the general case) might be difficult or impossible to write.

Answer (score 4):

You could do like this:

```
template <typename Head, typename... Tail> struct Types{
   typedef typename std::decay<Head>::type ReturnType;
   //typedef std::decay_t<Head> ReturnType; // C++14 equivalent
};
template <typename... Args>
auto make_vector(Args&&... args)
{

    return std::vector<typename Types<Args...>::ReturnType>{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}
```

Note that,the code select first parameter type as vector template parameter,  all the Args type need same or convertable.

Comment: It would be better to use `std::decay` on `Head`, so you can pass l-values.

Comment: You can make that shorter with a using alias and `std::decay_t`.